# Setting CLASSPATH within Docker container using Dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, jar, dockerfile, classpath

I have been trying to "dockerize" a microservice that I have built using java. However, I am having some issues with the classpath when using Docker. I am on a Linux machine using java open jdk 1.8. My dockerfile looks something like:

```
FROM openjdk:version

#`Make the directories I need
RUN mkdir -p /opt/service/libs

ENV LIBS_PATH=/opt/service/libs
ENV CLASSPATH=LIBS_PATH"/*"

COPY ./target/libs $LIBS_PATH
COPY ./target/MY_SERVICE.jar $LIBS_PATH

ENTRYPOINT java -cp $CLASSPATH "com.org.service.mainClass"
```

I have noticed when I do this and I echo the $CLASSPATH inside of the docker container, (using docker run), it returns all of the adresses of the jar files, but with a space in between instead of a : seperator. This implies two things, it knows where all of these jar files are and that the jar files have been successfully copied. I still get an error on the java -cp line. The error is as follows:

> Error: Could not find or load main class .opt.service.libs.FirstJarInLibsFolder.jar

If I change the `CLASSPATH` to have the `:` separators where it is supposed to, I instead get the error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.org.service.mainClass

even though my JAR contains that class.

Any thoughts on what it could be?

I have tried what is detailed above.

Comment: Specifying a classpath with spaces separating the elements is incorrect and won’t work. Show us your attempt using colons.

Comment: Also please verify that the name of the class is correct; the convention is that class names begin with a capital letter, so `MainClass` instead of `mainClass`

Comment: @TimMoore Hi Tim, I did not set these as spaces, that is just how the $CLASSPATH environment variables appears after I do: ENV CLASSPATH="/opt/service/libs/*" as shown in the question. To use colon seperators I copied the output of $echo CLASSPATH and did a replace on all " ", with ":", then it finds the MainClass, but not the other jars.

Comment: @Marcono1234 Hi! Sorry about that typo, yes the name is MainClass. I just typod when making the question.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks incorrect:

```
ENV CLASSPATH=LIBS_PATH"/*"
```

It should probably have a `$` before the variable name, see also the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement).

```
ENV CLASSPATH=$LIBS_PATH"/*"
```

Additionally to be safe you should probably put quotes around the `java -cp` argument:

```
ENTRYPOINT java -cp "$CLASSPATH" "com.org.service.MainClass"
```

(As mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76075609/setting-classpath-within-docker-container-using-dockerfile?noredirect=1#comment134215962_76075609), this also uses the correct capitalization of `MainClass`)

---

> when I do this and I echo the $CLASSPATH inside of the docker container, (using docker run), it returns all of the adresses of the jar files, but with a space in between

This probably performs wildcard expansion in the shell for the `*` in the classpath; you would have to run `echo "$CLASSPATH"` (with quotes) to prevent this and verify that the path is correct. The result from the wildcard expansion might not necessarily be the same as how `java` behaves. For example as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/219585) the shell will expand `*.jar` just fine, but passing it to `java -cp` will not work, you will have to use only `*` (as you have done).